# Getting multiple of the same entry in listview

Tags: c#, xamarin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm making an app that scans for BLE devices and displays them in a ListView.
The problem is that when I once it displays the devices once but if I scan twice it result the devices twice etc.

This is the code what I got so far. In Mainpage.cs I create an ObservableCollection where I store the devices and which I clear everytime I call the scan methode.

```
    <StackLayout Margin="15,15,10,15" >
        <Label Text="Paired Devices" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontSize="Subtitle"/>
        <ListView x:Name="paired" ItemsSource="{Binding deviceList}" ItemTapped="Paired_ItemTapped" BackgroundColor="White" SeparatorColor="Black">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Mainpage.cs

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(ble.State == BluetoothState.Off)
            {
                DisplayAlert("Bluetooth", "Please turn on bluetooth", "OK");
            }
            deviceList.Clear();
            adapter.DeviceDiscovered += (s, a) =>
              {
                  if (a.Device.Name != null)
                  {
                      deviceList.Add(a.Device);
                  }                  
                  Console.WriteLine(deviceList.Count);
              };

            if (!ble.Adapter.IsScanning)
            {
               adapter.StartScanningForDevicesAsync();
            }
        }
```

Comment: all you have to do is to check whether device already exists before adding a.Device

Comment: Was thinking way do difficult. Thx this worked.

Comment: @Shadow, Not sure if you have solved your issue now, if not, you can use linq to check where device already exist. `var item = deviceList.FirstOrDefault(i=>i.Name== a.Device.Name);
            if(item!=null)
            {
                //delete thie item from list.
            }`

Answer (score 1):

You have not shown the entire code here which you should have. So without that this is simply conjecture. The most probable cause to me of this occurring is you are adding the values to **deviceList** without removing the previous items.

Make sure when you are adding the items to **deviceList** to remove the old items in your Collection by either instantiating a new object of your Collection or by deleting unwanted (old) items from your Collection before adding any new items to it.

Comment: Please upload the backend code where you clear and update the list

Comment: Would be `deviceList.Clear();` be enough

Comment: If you are using an ObservableCollection Clear should suffice